# How to disable Windows 11 taskbar tooltips?

Tags: taskbar, windows-11

I have windows 11 and am using [startallback](https://www.startallback.com/).  [startallback](https://www.startallback.com/) is an alternate UI for Win 11 designed to restore classic UI elements "*from Windows 7, Windows 10 and third-party taskbar and start menu styles.*"   I am often working in a terminal where the line I'm writing is at the bottom of the screen and taskbar tooltips keep getting in my way like in the screen below.  How can I turn off these annoying tooltips?

[image]

Comment: I think that is something to do with your App.  Nothing like that on standard Windows 11 machines here.

Comment: See StartAllBack for Windows 11 [Support Forum](https://msfn.org/board/topic/183013-startallback-for-windows-11/)

Comment: OMG I hate these so much!  Always in the way of what I need to do.

Comment: Nope, it's nothing to do with the app. This is standard taskbar behaviour in Windows 11 and has been in Windows since as far as I can remember. If you check online you will see hundreds of posts on Microsoft Forums, complete with the incredibly helpful responses from MVPs who can't fail but to completely misunderstand the very clearly written descriptions of this problem. I still haven't solved it, the answer below does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I think that your cursor moves over the taskbar icons, so you're seeing
a tooltip about the program under the mouse.

You may set the display time of this notification to very long,
so the mouse might have the time to clear off the taskbar:

- Run `regedit`
- Position to the key
  `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced`
- Right-click the `Advanced` key and select
  *New > DWORD (32-bit) value*
- Name the new value `ExtendedUIHoverTime`
- Give it a large value (in milliseconds)
- Log out and back in.

Be careful with registry updates, possibly creating first a
System restore point. To undo the fix, delete the item
`ExtendedUIHoverTime` and log out/in.